# reload totally a page but keep initial post data following a new choice of select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, post

In my Symfony project I have a view who recover post data from a form.

In this view I have a select tag like this:

```
<select id="selectedChoice" name="form[selectedChoice]">
  <option value="{{ slug }}" selected>value1</option> <!-- first choice I made before on the first form -->
  <option disabled="disabled">-------------------</option>
  <option value="{{ slug }}">value2</option>
</select>
```

In fact I populate this select by a dynamic query following the current POST data.

But If I choice another value, the page has to refresh but have to reconsider the dynamic value of choice selected, that is to say the initial POST data I recover have to consider the new choice.

To better explain:
The initial POST data come from a form like this
I have a select populated with product category, a date and a location. I submit the form and it redirect me on a page where I need to recover these data. It the case for now.

But the other select of the other page is the same as the first e-g product category. If this value change, all the request change too, I have to consider this point.

**example:**
my fist form:

```
<select name="productCategory">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose a category</option>
  {% for currentCategory in arrayCategory %}
    <option value="{{ path('product_by_choice', {'slug': currentCategory.slug}) }}">{{ currentCategory.name }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>

<input type="text" id="zipCode" name="location"/>

<input type="text" id="datetimepicker" name="deliveryDate">

<button type="submit"><b>Ask for product</b></button>
```

So as you can see, I send this initial POSTdate and it redirect me to another where I poulate some field with (for example a select choice with products mapped with the category I selected the first time)

If I change my choice in the new page, how can I recover the same datas but following the new choice.

My javascript looks like this for now:

```
$('#selectedChoice').change(function() {
      window.location.reload(Routing.generate('product_by_choice', {slug: $(this).val()} ));
    });
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
public function quoteRequestByProductAction(Request $request, $slug, $session = null)
{
  // recover the session
  $session = $request->getSession();

  // recover data from previous form
  $location = $request->request->get('location');
  $deliveryDate = $request->request->get('deliveryDate');

  $productCategory = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:ProductCategory')->findOneBySlug($slug);

  $arrayProduct = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Product')->findByCategory($productCategory);

  $newProduct = new Product;

  $form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $newProduct);

        ->add('productCategory', 'entity', array(
                                          'required' => true,
                                          'class' => 'MyBundle:ProductCategory',
                                          'property' =>  'name',
                                          'choice_value' => 'slug',
                                          'choices_as_values' => true,
                                          'multiple' => false,
                                          'preferred_choices' => array($productCategory),

               ))
         ->add('product', 'entity', array(
                                      'required' => true,
                                      'class' => 'MyBundle:Product',
                                      'property' =>  'name',
                                      'choice_value' => 'slug',
                                      'choices' => $arrayProduct,
                                      'choices_as_values' => true,
                                      'multiple' => false,
                                      'mapped' => true,
               ))

}
```

Comment: can you post the controller code

Comment: @elkorchianas see my edit I wrote the controller of the second view where I recover my POST datas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to recover previous post data after a reload but there are ways around this issue.

- You can use a session handler to store the data that you need to hang onto and just check your session variables if the post data isn't there as expected. (This doesn't really apply to your task but is worth mentioning if you wanted to retain post data over multiple page views)
- You can change the reload javascript into a post(submit) of its own and pre-select the passed option while also rendering any additional selects or options as needed.
- Or you can use an ajax request to pull data from the server and simply change your form without submitting it or reloading the page.

For your application I think the ajax method would be the most user friendly as it doesn't involve the entire page reloading. A quick google search turned up this example http://tutorialzine.com/2011/11/chained-ajax-selects-jquery/

If you didn't want to go down that route however then I would recommend changing your javascript to submit the form then check the form for completeness in your php code. If the form is still incomplete then redraw the form and make sure the additional select boxes (or anything else needed) gets rendered.